# Saving form2 from form1 button

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a form called form1 that allows me to create another form called form2, form2 has a textbox that I can input text into.  On form1 I have a save button to save the text in form2 as a .txt file.  I am currently having issues with  one of my last steps where my current method does not exist and I am not sure how to fix this without messing anything else up.

Currently I have completed the following code for my button so I can save

```
private void bmSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveText = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveText.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveText.Filter = "TXT Files(*.txt;)|*.txt;";
            if (saveText.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(saveText.FileName)))
                    write.Write(TextFile);           
            }

        }
```

Now under my second form(form2) I only have the following code

```
 public  partial class TextDocumentForm : Form
    {
        public TextDocumentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string TextFile
        {
            get { return tbTextDoc.Text; }
            set { tbTextDoc.Text = value; }      
        }
    }
```

My current issue lies with my `public string TextFile` where I get the error that the current method does not exist in Form 1.  Being fairly new I am unsure as to how to proceed and would appreciate any help as I have been stumped with this for a while.

Comment: you need an instance of form2 to call get the TextFile property from. Where do you create form2? If you are doing this in a member function of form1 you could store a reference to form2 in a member variable of form1 and then do write.Write(form2.TextFile) in your save as click handler

Comment: Form2 right now gets created from form1 button(I am using MDI, so it is created as a child form.).  I have tried a couple steps but I am still lost.

Answer (score 0):

`public string TextFile` is a member of Form2, and of course, form1 don't know it. You can try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm2 = new Form2();
        }

        private void ShowForm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            frm2.Show();
        }

        private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(frm2.TextFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the response as this has helped quite a lot.  One last issue I seem to be having is getting streamwriter to write the text from my textbox into the newly saved file ( At the moment I can save a text document to my desktop but it is empty.)  I was trying to use  `write.Write(frm2.TextFile); `

Comment: @Adrian: I see no problem here, you need to debug on this line `write.Write(frm2.TextFile);` and check value of frm2.TextFile. And one small thing, you save to C:\, maybe need admin privilege.

Comment: I managed to tinker with it and save, but if I try to create new forms I am unable to (my create button now only creates one instance of form2, even if I click it multiple times.).  If I close that form and click my new form button I get an exception saying 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TextDocumentForm'.'  My best guess is it is an issue with how I am retrieving the textbox input but I am not really sure.

Comment: maybe you should Hide not Close form.